# Open and parse a file

Tags: c

I'm working through a programming project for a course I'm in and I'm struggling with what I think is just a fundamental misunderstanding of C programming and was hoping SO could help. I'm trying to open a file with this piece of code:

```
FILE *fp;
if(fp = fopen("testfile.txt", "r") == NULL){
    perror("fileopen");
}
```

When I try to compile that code I getting this warning:
warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Then, when I try to read the file I'm getting a segmentation fault.

I'm an experienced java programmer but there is something about pointers and data types in C that I just don't understand.

Thanks!

Comment: Add extra brackets around the (fp=fopen())==NULL bit

Comment: Side note: Recommend opening text files for reading with "rt".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is misinterpretation of operator precedence. `fopen("testfile.txt", "r") == NULL` gets evaluated first, and the result (1 or 0) gets stored in the pointer `fp` instead of the actual return value from `fopen("testfile.txt", "r")`.

You should actually use  `(fp = fopen("testfile.txt", "r")) == NULL` in your if-statement. Or, if you are just beginning, it might be better to break this down a bit and write:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("testfile.txt", "r");
if(fp == NULL){
    perror("fileopen");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Other people have pointed out, things go wrong in the `if`. To avoid that, split the thing. It will be more readable and less error prone:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("testfile.txt", "r");
if(fp  == NULL) {
    perror("fileopen");
}
```

or, what you see a lot:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("testfile.txt", "r");
if(!fp) {
    perror("fileopen");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a pair of parens:

```
(fp = fopen("testfile.txt", "r") == NULL)
```

is parsed as

```
(fp = (fopen("testfile.txt", "r") == NULL))
```

which evaluates the comparison, giving an `int`, which is then stored in a pointer-valued variable, hence the warning.

It should be

```
((fp = fopen("testfile.txt", "r")) == NULL)
```